# Splitting up Swift code in multiple lines for better readability

Tags: swift

It seems like it's not possible to do something like this:

```
println("this is a very very 
  very long text")
```

Is there a workaround for this ?

Comment: Hi please explain further to what you want. I.e wrapping the text before the margin of the editor. Or a new line in the text.

Comment: i dont know anything besides println("Line 1" + "\n" +
 "Line 2")``

Comment: Generally speaking, is it possible to make the code more readable without changing the wrapping options of the editor ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
println("lorem ipsum" +
"ipsum lorem" +
"muspi merol")
```

Comment: This kind of works, but not quite for other types of code, I am gonna accept the answer anyways because it doesn't seem to be a solution for it.

Comment: You are most likely right but IMO it would be best edit your question to reflect what you really want rather than accept a wrong answer.

Comment: @markhunte whats wrong with my answer? That's workaround imo.

Comment: @juniperi Nothing and sorry my mistake. I though the code altered the output. Your answer is good and I will +1 it

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Swift does not support trailing backslash in source code lines, like C and lots of other languages:

```
// works in plain C
printf("this is a very very\
very long text");
```

Neither it does automatic concatenation of adjacent string literals, like C does:

```
// works in plain C
printf("this is a very very"
       "very long text");
```

So the only way you can make it work in current Swift is to explicitly concatenate:

```
// Swift
println("this is a very very" +
        "very long text")
```